# из String в Array

Tags: java, android

Есть много текста, разделенного определённым тегом, допустим:

```
string = "Cat<tag>Dog<tag>Fox<tag>Snake";
```

надо получить:

```
array = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fox', 'Snake'];
```

Чтобы можно было вызвать:

```
array[2] = 'Fox';
```

На JavaScript + jquery отлично работал код:

```
arr = string.split('<tag>');
```

И как это заставить работать?

```
String[] types = result.split("<br2>");
    for(int i = 0; i < types.length; i++){
        types[i] = types[i].split("<br1>");
    }
}
```

Что бы было типо: types[i][0]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да вроде также:

```
String string = "Cat<tag>Dog<tag>Fox<tag>Snake";
String[] splitedString = string.split("<tag>");
```

Comment: Спасибо, только сейчас дошло что не так делал, использовал:ArrayList  splitedString = string.split("<tag>");

Comment: А ещё, как сделать массив из масивов? В шапку добавил пример не рабочего кода

Comment: Вы html хотите распарсить чтоли?

Comment: Нет,в базе данных есть таблица users которая выводиться в моё приложение в виде id<tag1>login<tag1>pass<tag2> id<tag1>login<tag1>pass<tag2>

Comment: Вам, по идее, надо тогда базу оптимизировать. Сплитами без костылей просто так не отделаться.